# How do you create tests for "make check" with GNU autotools

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, automated-tests, autotools

I'm using GNU autotools for the build system on a particular project. I want to start writing automated tests for verifcation. I would like to just type "make check" to have it automatically run these. My project is in C++, although I am still curious about writing automated tests for other languages as well.

*Is this compatible with pretty much every unit testing framework out there (I was thinking of using cppunit)? How do I hook these unit testing frameworks into make check? Can I make sure that I don't require the unit test software to be installed to be able to configure and build the rest of the project?*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To make test run when you issue `make check`, you need to add them to the `TESTS` variable

Assuming you've already built the executable that runs the unit tests, you just add the name of the executable to the TESTS variable like this:

```
TESTS=my-test-executable
```

It should then be automatically run when you `make check`, and if the executable returns a non-zero value, it will report that as a test failure.  If you have multiple unit test executables, just list them all in the `TESTS` variable:

```
TESTS=my-first-test my-second-test my-third-test
```

and they will all get run.

Comment: you may also want to use the TESTS_ENVIRONMENT variable if you need to tweak the environment in which your tests will run, for example PATH.

Comment: And of course, if you want to build the tests from source but not install them, then you would probably specify their names in the `check_PROGRAMS` Automake variable, and define any needed sources and build options just as you would for any other target.

Comment: Right/wrong/or indifferent the tests are not in the tarball when you do a `make dist`.

Comment: Complete autotools beginner question - which file should have the line TESTS=my-test-executable ?

Answer (score 14):

I'm using [Check 0.9.10](https://libcheck.github.io/check/)

```
    configure.ac
    Makefile.am
    src/Makefile.am
    src/foo.c
    tests/check_foo.c
    tests/Makefile.am
```

1. `./configure.ac`

   PKG_CHECK_MODULES([CHECK], [check >= 0.9.10])
2. `./tests/Makefile.am` for test codes

   ```
   TESTS = check_foo
   check_PROGRAMS = check_foo
   check_foo_SOURCES = check_foo.c $(top_builddir)/src/foo.h
   check_foo_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@
   ```
3. and write test code, `./tests/check_foo.c`

   ```
   START_TEST (test_foo)
   {
       ck_assert( foo() == 0 );
       ck_assert_int_eq( foo(), 0);
   }
   END_TEST

   /// And there are some tcase_xxx codes to run this test
   ```

Using check you can use timeout and raise signal. it is very helpful.

Comment: "Check" site's Tutorial( https://libcheck.github.io/check/doc/check_html/check_3.html ) helps me.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be asking 2 questions in the first paragraph.

The first is about adding tests to the GNU autotools toolchain - but those tests, if I'm understanding you correctly, are for both validating that the environment necessary to build your application exists (dependent libraries and tools) as well as adapt the build to the environment (platform specific differences).

The second is about unit testing your C++ application and where to invoke those tests, you've proposed doing so from the autotools tool chain, presumably from the configure script.  Doing that isn't conventional though - putting a 'test' target in your Makefile is a more conventional way of executing your test suite.  The typical steps for building and installing an application with autotools (at least from a user's perspective, not from your, the developer, perspective) is to run the configure script, then run make, then optionally run make test and finally make install.

For the second issue, not wanting cppunit to be a dependency, why not just distribute it with your c++ application?  Can you just put it right in what ever archive format you're using (be it tar.gz, tar.bz2 or .zip) along with your source code.  I've used cppunit in the past and was happy with it, having used JUnit and other xUnit style frameworks.

Comment: any insight into the down vote?  Did you feel the question wasn't directly addressed?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method without dependencies:

```
#src/Makefile.am
check_PROGRAMS = test1 test2
test1_SOURCES = test/test1.c code_needed_to_test1.h code_needed_to_test1.c
test2_SOURCES = test/test2.c code_needed_to_test2.h code_needed_to_test2.c
TESTS = $(check_PROGRAMS)
```

The `make check` will naturally work and show formatted and summarized output:

```
$ make check
...
PASS: test1
PASS: test2
============================================================================
Testsuite summary for foo 1.0
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 2
# PASS:  2
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  0
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
```

1. When you do a `make dist` nothing from `src/test/*` will be
   in the tarball. Test code is not in the dist, only source will be.
2. When you do a `make distcheck` it will run `make check` and run your tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Automake's `TESTS` to run programs generated with `check_PROGRAMS` but this will assume that you are using a log driver and a compiler for the output. It is probably easier to still use `check_PROGRAMS` but to invoke the test suite using a local rule in the Makefile:

```
check_PROGRAMS=testsuite

testsuite_SOURCES=...
testsuite_CFLAGS=...
testsuite_LDADD=...

check-local:
    ./testsuite
```