# How can I build Unittests with check?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, check-framework

I want to test my C code and decide to using check as testing Framework.
But I don't understand how to compile the code? 
In the tutorial they have already very huge makefiles, but they do not explain how to build them or what gcc flags I need.

How can I execute my simple tests?

Comment: See my answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20277301/1309262

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to acomplish with autotools. In **configure.ac** you check for existance of Check unit testing framework on the target system:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([CHECK],[check >= 0.8.2],[have_check="yes"],
  AC_MSG_WARN(['Check' unit testing framework not found. It would be impossible to run unit tests!"])
  [have_check="no"])
```

In **Makefile.am** you specify what files and how to compile to build unit tests:

```
if HAVE_CHECK
check_PROGRAMS = bin/some_unit_tests 
bin_some_unit_tests_SOURCES = source1.c source2.c ...
bin_some_unit_tests_CFLAGS = -g -pg -O2 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage ...
bin_some_unit_tests_LDFLAGS = -g -pg -no-install
bin_some_unit_tests_LDADD = @CHECK_LIBS@
TESTS = bin/some_unit_tests
TESTS_ENVIRONMENT = CK_FORK=yes
CK_VERBOSITY = verbose
CLEANFILES = some_unit_tests.log
endif
```

Then you run unit test by issuing the command:

```
make check
```

By using -pg flag you would be able to obtain profiling information from executing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am not familiar with Check.

I will recommend using [CppUTest](http://www.cpputest.org/) and reading [TDD For Embedded C](http://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c).
It has a good explanation and works on both C and C++.

Another option is Unity, also documented in the referenced book.

Comment: Last version is from 2009 because it's feature-complete and no bug have been found in this time. Judge the activity of the projects by activity of mailing lists not only how recent last release was.

Comment: As I mentioned in my message, I'm not familiar with Check. IMHO the last checkin date is a factor in choosing an application, not the only one, but it is in my top 10 factors. Anyway, I will remove my remark on the version date, sorry if I offended someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could get an archive file called "libcheck.a" after "configure->make->make install". Usually the libcheck.a will be installed into "/usr/lib" or "/usr/local/lib" and Gcc could find the location of libcheck.a automatically. What you need to do is to add -lcheck option to your compiling commandline,such as "gcc -o test_add test_add.c -lcheck".

Beside check, There are also many other framework for c unit testing, e.g. [lcut](http://code.google.com/p/lcut), [cmockery](http://code.google.com/p/cmockery)

Answer (score 0):

There are open source projects that use check for unit testing. One example is TORQUE. You can check out the source using svn. Currently you'd want the trunk to see unit tests - 
svn co svn://svn.clusterresources.com/torque/trunk

Look at the directory src/lib/Libutils/test/resizable_array for one example of how to set things up. Like bsa2000's answer says, there's a lot of setup in terms of altering makefiles.